# Presenting Numbers in Particle Physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, measurements, weak-interaction

We got some data from the OPAL-detector at CERN and were supposed to analyze the decay of the $Z^0$-particle. In order to do so, we had to write a Python-scriptum. Now, in Python, we obtained the following data (these are cross-sections) that we put into a matrix:

```
[[ 0.53927461  0.30761924  0.51209875  7.42210069]
 [ 0.87972478  0.65251433  0.7126011  14.30873651]
 [ 1.2448176   1.21864806  1.21730139 25.85702364]
 [ 1.72807109  1.91199577  1.73165599 40.6942694 ]
 [ 1.16536283  1.36456886  1.24511802 29.09186684]
 [ 0.4688968   0.6326488   0.70868107 13.72056982]
 [ 0.2458198   0.37770554  0.36999498  8.26574927]]
```

And here are the errors we obtained for the cross-sections:

```
[[0.0372435  0.02320842 0.03678235 0.12068507]
 [0.03841575 0.02805575 0.03509138 0.15108899]
 [0.05142342 0.04551084 0.05371951 0.25750689]
 [0.02930665 0.02849595 0.03188951 0.24879171]
 [0.09251979 0.10566853 0.1203519  2.00139233]
 [0.03913862 0.04076568 0.05041809 0.22244006]
 [0.02569141 0.02738741 0.03208928 0.14702153]]
```

Now, I don't know how to write these data down into our text; since our assistant is ill, he didn't reply to my email. The assistant is a researcher in experimental physics, more specifically in Particle Physics.

So what would be the usual format to present these data? Would it be:

```
[0.53927 0.30762 0.51210 7.42210]
```

(just 5 digits after the dot)
or

```
[5.39275\cdot 10^{-1} 3.07619\cdot 10^{-1} 5.12099\cdot 10^{-1} 7.42210]
```

Your experience would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what the conventions are in particle physics either: hence I would try to find a bunch of papers reporting data like this and see how they do it. As general observation, adding the exponents do not improve clarity (more text, some will be -1 and some 0 in confusing ways). Should the errors be reported in a separate matrix? Also, what is the number of significant digits? Is it really 5 for everything?

Comment: Thanks for your comment so far! I found two publications that didn't have a bunch of data, only numbers like 837.2, 17, 25.6, etc. (and this makes since since they were looking at the number of myons, electrons, ...).